# Difference between WebMvcConfigurer and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-security

What is the difference between those two? When do I use one over the other?

In the [Spring Security Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration) it says that, among other things, `WebMvcConfigurer` has the following feature:

> Require authentication to every URL in your application

The `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` example shown in [HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity) says:

> Ensures that any request to our application requires the user to be authenticated.

Isn't that the same?

**EDIT**

These two types of configs seem to serve different purposes, I just don't quite understand yet, when to use which: What are the two distinct scenarios for each of the config types?

In the introduction to the **HttpSecuriy** section, it says

> How does Spring Security know that we want to require all users to be authenticated? How does Spring Security know we want to support form based authentication?

So right now I am thinking: the first one says what should happen when authenticating a user and the second says in what cases do users need to be authenticated. Is that correct?

E.g., the first config "Generate a login form for you" and the second determines, when that login form should be shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does appear to be a documentation bug (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6809):

> This raises confusion about the role of WebMvcConfigurer in Spring Security and the use cases for WebMvcConfigurer vs WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
>
> Most likely the intention in the example was:
>
> ```
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
> ```